# How to add multiple policy using loop in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam, amazon-sqs, policy

I am trying to create multiple SNS topic subscription in the SQS. I do have the config file like below in json format

```
"snsSubscriptionArns": [
        "arn:aws:sns:<region>:<accountno>:test1",
        "arn:aws:sns:<region>:<accountno>:test2",
        "arn:aws:sns:<region>:<accountno>:test3"
        ]
```

Above mentioned Arns will be based on the requirement. It's dynamic. It can be 0, can be 5.. I am trying to create policy using the below

```
locals {
  # Load all of the data from json
  config = jsondecode(file("testsqs.json"))
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "sns_policy" {
  for_each = lookup(local.config, "snsSubscriptionArns", null) == null ? toset([]) : [ for i in local.config.snsSubscriptionArns : i ]
      statement {
      sid     = "topic-subscription-${each.key}"
      effect  = "Allow"
      actions = [
        "sqs:SendMessage"
      ]
      resources = [
        "test-arn"
      ]
      condition {
        test     = "ArnLike"
        variable = "aws:SourceArn"
        values = [
          "${each.key}"
        ]
      }
    }
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.sns_policy[each.key].json
  }
```

I need to collect all the policies and then I will use resource block to create SQS with above policy like below

```
resource "aws_sqs_queue_policy" "sqs_queue_policy" {
  queue_url = aws_sqs_queue.queue.id
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.sns_policy.json
}
```

But I am getting the below error msg.

```
Error: Unsupported argument

  on main.tf line 36, in data "aws_iam_policy_document" "sns_policy":  
  36:   policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.sns_policy[each.key].json

An argument named "policy" is not expected here.
```

It looks my approach is wrong in terraform. Could someone please guide me to achieve? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error message states that the data block is not expecting a `policy` argument. This makes sense given 1. the data exports a policy 2. you are attempting to refer to the export from the data as an input, which would be a self-referential circular dependency if this was possible. Besides fixing the error by removing the `policy` argument, is there anything else erroring or different from what you are attempting to achieve here?

Comment: Hi @MattSchuchard - Thanks for the quick response. I updated the code in the Question with additional requirement. Using the cumalative policy, I need to create policy using resource block. Just wonder how it can be achieved if "policy" removed in the data block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the docs for [data source aws_iam_policy_document](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/iam_policy_document), there is no `policy` attribute. I believe either of these two options should work. You are very close.

Given the source json file testsqs.json:

```json
{
  "snsSubscriptionArns": [
    "arn:aws:sns:<region>:<accountno>:test1",
    "arn:aws:sns:<region>:<accountno>:test2",
    "arn:aws:sns:<region>:<accountno>:test3"
  ]
}
```

and main.tf:

```
locals {
  config = jsondecode(file("testsqs.json"))
  arns   = lookup(local.config, "snsSubscriptionArns", [])
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "sns_policy_one_statement" {
  statement {
    actions   = ["sqs:SendMessage"]
    resources = ["test-arn"]
    condition {
      test     = "ArnLike"
      variable = "aws:SourceArn"
      values   = local.arns
    }
  }
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "sns_policy_many_statements" {
  dynamic "statement" {
    for_each = local.arns

    content {
      sid       = "topic-subscription-${statement.key}"
      actions   = ["sqs:SendMessage"]
      resources = ["test-arn"]
      condition {
        test     = "ArnLike"
        variable = "aws:SourceArn"
        values   = [statement.value]
      }
    }
  }
}

output "sns_policy_one_statement" {
  value = data.aws_iam_policy_document.sns_policy_one_statement.json
}

output "sns_policy_many_statements" {
  value = data.aws_iam_policy_document.sns_policy_many_statements.json
}
```

You get outputs like:

```
Changes to Outputs:
  + sns_policy_many_statements = jsonencode(
        {
          + Statement = [
              + {
                  + Action    = "sqs:SendMessage"
                  + Condition = {
                      + ArnLike = {
                          + "aws:SourceArn" = "arn:aws:sns:<region>:<accountno>:test1"
                        }
                    }
                  + Effect    = "Allow"
                  + Resource  = "test-arn"
                  + Sid       = "topic-subscription-0"
                },
              + {
                  + Action    = "sqs:SendMessage"
                  + Condition = {
                      + ArnLike = {
                          + "aws:SourceArn" = "arn:aws:sns:<region>:<accountno>:test2"
                        }
                    }
                  + Effect    = "Allow"
                  + Resource  = "test-arn"
                  + Sid       = "topic-subscription-1"
                },
              + {
                  + Action    = "sqs:SendMessage"
                  + Condition = {
                      + ArnLike = {
                          + "aws:SourceArn" = "arn:aws:sns:<region>:<accountno>:test3"
                        }
                    }
                  + Effect    = "Allow"
                  + Resource  = "test-arn"
                  + Sid       = "topic-subscription-2"
                },
            ]
          + Version   = "2012-10-17"
        }
    )
  + sns_policy_one_statement   = jsonencode(
        {
          + Statement = [
              + {
                  + Action    = "sqs:SendMessage"
                  + Condition = {
                      + ArnLike = {
                          + "aws:SourceArn" = [
                              + "arn:aws:sns:<region>:<accountno>:test1",
                              + "arn:aws:sns:<region>:<accountno>:test2",
                              + "arn:aws:sns:<region>:<accountno>:test3",
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                  + Effect    = "Allow"
                  + Resource  = "test-arn"
                  + Sid       = ""
                },
            ]
          + Version   = "2012-10-17"
        }
    )
```

You only need [for_each](https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/for_each) at the resource level if you want to create multiple of that resource. In your case, I think you only need one policy. You can decide which works for `aws_sqs_queue_policy`. This uses the [dynamic block](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks).

Answer (score 1):

`policy` is not a valid attribute for `iam_policy_document` data source see : https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/iam_policy_document

It is expected on `aws_iam_policy` data source, you must create `aws_iam_policy` resources with a foreach loop